# SequelizeConnectionRefusedError - Trying to access my deployed web app with Firebase/Google Cloud SQL

Tags: firebase, cloud

I set-up a web app with Firebase and Google Cloud SQL but I always get the same error. Can you help me?

```
{ SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED /cloudsql/pet-hotel-275016:us-central1:pet-hotel/.s.PGSQL.5432
    at connection.connect.err (/srv/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:116:24)
    at Connection.connectingErrorHandler (/srv/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:140:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Socket.reportStreamError (/srv/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:71:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:66:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
  message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED /cloudsql/pet-hotel-275016:us-central1:pet-hotel/.s.PGSQL.5432',
  locations: [ { line: 2, column: 3 } ],
  path: [ 'settingsFind' ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what the console looks like

[Console looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7qb6.png)